# Using SQL to find Occurence of Node with field values within

Tags: sql, xml

I have a SQL trigger which reads from XML files like the one below, and imports the values into relevant fields in a form.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2016-08-18T07:03:22">
    <MPSExport>
        <ReportID>WR_2245</ReportID>
        <ActivityID>0</ActivityID>
        <Hours>13.75</Hours>
    </MPSExport>
    <MPSExport>
        <ReportID>WR_2245</ReportID>
        <ActivityID>115810</ActivityID>
        <Method>5</Method>
        <Herbicide_1>5</Herbicide_1>
        <Herbicide_Rate_1>0.05</Herbicide_Rate_1>
        <Herbicide_Qty_1>20</Herbicide_Qty_1>
        <Herbicide_2>2</Herbicide_2>
        <Herbicide_Rate_2>0.5</Herbicide_Rate_2>
        <Herbicide_Qty_2>60</Herbicide_Qty_2>
        <Herbicide_IsSurfactant_2>1</Herbicide_IsSurfactant_2>
        <Comments>Test.</Comments>
    </MPSExport>
    <MPSExport>
        <ReportID>WR_2245</ReportID>
        <ActivityID>115810</ActivityID>
        <Method>8</Method>
        <Herbicide_1>10</Herbicide_1>
        <Herbicide_Rate_1>2</Herbicide_Rate_1>
        <Herbicide_Qty_1>30</Herbicide_Qty_1>
        <Herbicide_2>2</Herbicide_2>
        <Herbicide_Rate_2>1</Herbicide_Rate_2>
        <Herbicide_Qty_2>70</Herbicide_Qty_2>
        <Herbicide_IsSurfactant_2>1</Herbicide_IsSurfactant_2>
        <Weed_1>5266</Weed_1>
        <Weed_2>5261</Weed_2>
        <Weed_3>5884</Weed_3>
        <Weed_4>4004</Weed_4>
        <Comments>WR_2245 finished off some of WMA_620&apos;s budget (MPS BLM Bal Est BC). Began treating rambling dock and winter cherry.</Comments>
        <FollowUpNotes>Continue to work through the Zone</FollowUpNotes>
    </MPSExport>
</dataroot>
```

As there are fields repeated with the same name, they correspond to fields in different tabs on the form. To differentiate these I used

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) AS ROW, 'Method', CAST([Method]AS VARCHAR(2)) FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'dataroot/MPSExport') WITH ([Method] [nvarchar](max) 'Method') WHERE [Method] IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL.....continue with other fields
```

The problem is, if someone leaves the first occurrence of the 'Method' field in the XML file blank but the second occurrence has a value, my import process will populate the first Method field on the form with the second Method value in the XML file.

Instead of grouping by field name repeating, is there a way to group XML fields by the parent node, i.e. MPSExport?

As a test on one field I tried

```
SELECT 'Method', CAST([Method]AS VARCHAR(2)),
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.X) AS ROW
FROM @XML.nodes('dataroot/MPSExport') AS T(X)
CROSS APPLY
OPENXML(@hDoc, 'dataroot/MPSExport') WITH ([Method] [nvarchar](max) 'Method')
WHERE [Method] IS NOT NULL
```

but it just gives me the following

```
Method  5   1
Method  8   2
Method  5   3
Method  8   4
Method  5   5
Method  8   6
```

whereas I want it to show

```
Method  5  2
Method  8  3
```

5 and 8 are the value, and 2 and 3 are the occurrence of the MPSExport node.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: `FROM OPENXML` is outdated and should not be used any more.

Better use the *up-to-date* XML methods like `.value()`,`.nodes()`, `.modify()` and `.query()`

Your code with `CROSS APPLY` generates an *each-with-each* join, hence the multiple row result.

Your problem is to number **all Methods**, but to show only the rows with a value.

My approach: Use `.nodes()` to get all `<MSPExport>`-elements and number them whether there is a `<Method>` or not. Then take this derived table and filter for Methods, which are not null.

This might have a problem, if there could be more than one `<Method>` below one `<MSPExport>`...

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2016-08-18T07:03:22">
    <MPSExport>
        <ReportID>WR_2245</ReportID>
        <ActivityID>0</ActivityID>
        <Hours>13.75</Hours>
    </MPSExport>
    <MPSExport>
        <ReportID>WR_2245</ReportID>
        <ActivityID>115810</ActivityID>
        <Method>5</Method>
        <Herbicide_1>5</Herbicide_1>
        <Herbicide_Rate_1>0.05</Herbicide_Rate_1>
        <Herbicide_Qty_1>20</Herbicide_Qty_1>
        <Herbicide_2>2</Herbicide_2>
        <Herbicide_Rate_2>0.5</Herbicide_Rate_2>
        <Herbicide_Qty_2>60</Herbicide_Qty_2>
        <Herbicide_IsSurfactant_2>1</Herbicide_IsSurfactant_2>
        <Comments>Test.</Comments>
    </MPSExport>
    <MPSExport>
        <ReportID>WR_2245</ReportID>
        <ActivityID>115810</ActivityID>
        <Method>8</Method>
        <Herbicide_1>10</Herbicide_1>
        <Herbicide_Rate_1>2</Herbicide_Rate_1>
        <Herbicide_Qty_1>30</Herbicide_Qty_1>
        <Herbicide_2>2</Herbicide_2>
        <Herbicide_Rate_2>1</Herbicide_Rate_2>
        <Herbicide_Qty_2>70</Herbicide_Qty_2>
        <Herbicide_IsSurfactant_2>1</Herbicide_IsSurfactant_2>
        <Weed_1>5266</Weed_1>
        <Weed_2>5261</Weed_2>
        <Weed_3>5884</Weed_3>
        <Weed_4>4004</Weed_4>
        <Comments>WR_2245 finished off some of WMA_620&apos;s budget (MPS BLM Bal Est BC). Began treating rambling dock and winter cherry.</Comments>
        <FollowUpNotes>Continue to work through the Zone</FollowUpNotes>
    </MPSExport>
</dataroot>';
```

--Here's the query

```
WITH NumberdMethods AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [ROW]
          ,ex.value('Method[1]','int') AS Method
    FROM @xml.nodes('/dataroot/MPSExport') AS A(ex)
)
SELECT * 
FROM NumberdMethods
WHERE Method IS NOT NULL
```

The result

```
ROW Method
2   5
3   8
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for your quick response. I'll update my trigger. Very helpful.